# Decomposition of tuple with structured bindings into const, and const& variables

Tags: c++, c++20, structured-bindings

Trying to understand working of structured bindings with `const` and references in particular as `std::tuple` is decomposed into named variables.

In the following case, it makes sense that `a` would be of type `const int`, with `int&` for `b` since `int& const` == `int&`, but how come the type of `a1` isn't `const int&`? Is `&` only applied to the return object of `get()`?

```
int x;
std::tuple<int, int&> get()
{
    return std::tuple<int, int&>(9, x);
}

int main()
{
   const auto [a, b] = get();
   const auto& [a1, b1] = get(); 

   static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int, decltype(a)>); 
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<int&, decltype(b)>); 


   static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int, decltype(a1)>); 
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<int&, decltype(b1)>);
}
```

According to cpp-insights, that's how unpacking works. It's clear how it's `const int& a1`. however `static_assert` claims otherwise. Why the conflict? How else would the return from `get()` be decomposed?

```
const std::tuple<int, int &> __get12 = get();
const int && a = std::get<0UL>(static_cast<const std::tuple<int, int &> &&>(__get12));
int & b = std::get<1UL>(static_cast<const std::tuple<int, int &> &&>(__get12));

const std::tuple<int, int &> & __get13 = get();
const int & a1 = std::get<0UL>(__get13);
int & b1 = std::get<1UL>(__get13);
```

In simple terms, that's how I imagined would happen but it doesn't seem like it:

```
const auto& t = get(); 
const int& a1 = std::get<0>(t);
int& b1= std::get<1>(t);
```

**EDIT:**

The following works then that means structured binding does indeed not discard references, and perhaps it's just what `decltype` does as it returns the type of the element only not including the reference?

```
    std::tuple<int> tx = std::make_tuple(42);
    auto& [xz] = tx;
    decltype(xz) yz = 0;  // int& yz = 0;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, decltype(yz)>);
    xz = 31; // tx<0> => 31
```

Comment: I know that I can put references into tuples. It's allowed. It's legal. `std::tie` does that. But I will prefer to have my two remaining wisdom teeth yanked out before I will agree to write any code, myself, that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Structured bindings are not regular variables and are treated differently by `decltype`. The output of cppinsights is only a close approximation. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) says:

> `decltype(x)`, where `x` denotes a structured binding, names the *referenced type* of that structured binding. In the tuple-like case, this is the type returned by std::tuple_element, which may not be a reference even though a hidden reference is always introduced in this case. This effectively emulates the behavior of binding to a struct whose non-static data members have the types returned by tuple_element, with the referenceness of the binding itself being a mere implementation detail.

The reference qualifier (`&`) does apply to the intermediary object (named `__get31` in your question).

Conceptually, it helps to compare with a struct used in this way:

```
struct tup {
  int a;
  int& b;
};

tup& value = get();
```

In that case, even though `decltype(value)` is `tup &`, `decltype(value.a)` is `int`, just like the structured binding `a1` of a `std::tuple<int, int&> &` has a `decltype` of `int`.

Comment: so basically `decltype` doesn't run the reference type but just the type of the element itself? does that mean the type of `a1` is `const int&` then?

Comment: No, its type is `const int`. See my expanded answer.

Comment: `&` applies to the intermediary object but doesn't get propagated further but `const` does?

Comment: Yes. Just like the members of a const struct are const, but the members of a reference to a struct are not references.

Comment: `decltype(value.a)` is `int`, not `const int` (unlike the structured binding case).

Comment: Oops, I tried to stretch that comparison too far. Removed `const` from the answer.

Comment: @EtienneLaurin 1) If `a1` is still `const int`, then what's up with `decltype` naming a referenced type of the structured binding? Doesn't `decltype` return the exact type that's expected anyway? 2) What if `value` was `const tup`&`? Would `const` not make `tup::a` `const`?

Comment: do you mind providing more examples? (`const auto& tup`, `const tup`). So if you have `const tup value`, `decltype(value.a)` would get you `int` and not `const int` even though it technically is const

Comment: @xyf, for both `const tup& value` and `const tup value`, `decltype(value.a)` is `int`, which is the declared type of `a`. However, `decltype(value)` is `struct tup const &` and `struct tup const`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from cppreference(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

```cpp
float x{};
char  y{};
int   z{};
 
std::tuple<float&, char&&, int> tpl(x, std::move(y), z);
const auto& [a, b, c] = tpl;
// using Tpl = const std::tuple<float&, char&&, int>;
// `a` names a structured binding that refers to x (initialized from get<0>(tpl))
// decltype(a) is std::tuple_element<0, Tpl>::type, i.e. float&
// `b` names a structured binding that refers to y (initialized from get<1>(tpl))
// decltype(b) is std::tuple_element<1, Tpl>::type, i.e. char&&
// `c` names a structured binding that refers to the third component of tpl, get<2>(tpl)
// decltype(c) is std::tuple_element<2, Tpl>::type, i.e. const int
```

In `const auto& [a, b, c] = tpl;`, `&` applies to the unnamed object, which is a reference to `tpl`, and `const` propagates to each identifier. `const` for a reference is shallow: analogously, a const pointer to a non-const object.

`const auto& [a1, b1] = get();` in your example follows the same pattern. `&` is for the unnamed object, which is a reference to the returned tuple. `const` applies to `a1` and `b1`, but `b1` is a reference. So the types of `a1` and `b1` are `const int` and `int &`, respectively.

Each identifier is initialized with `std::get`, which always returns a reference, but their types are determined by `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`, where `i` is the i-th element and `E` is the type of an expression.

In the following example,

```cpp
std::tuple<int> tx = std::make_tuple(42);
auto& [xz] = tx;
decltype(xz) yz = 0;  // int& yz = 0; --> int yz = 0;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, decltype(yz)>);
xz = 31; // tx<0> => 31
```

the unnamed object is a reference to `tx`: the unnamed object == `tx`. The type of `xz` is `int`: the type of the zeroth element of the tuple. `xz` == zeroth element of `unnamed object` == zeroth element of `tx`, so `xz = 31;` modifies the value of `tx`.

FYI, Boost TypeIndex library gives accurate type information.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

int x;
std::tuple<int, int&> get()
{
    return std::tuple<int, int&>(9, x);
}

int main()
{
    const auto [a, b] = get();
    const auto& [a1, b1] = get();

    using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;
    std::cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(a)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
    std::cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(b)>().pretty_name() << '\n';

    std::cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(a1)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
    std::cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(b1)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
int const
int & __ptr64
int const
int & __ptr64
```